# Is it solvable? Sequence Recursive Formula Containing Summation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recursion

$ 
x_{k-1} = x_k + V_k*Max(Min([\frac{\sigma_{k+1}}{\sigma_{k}}(\frac{x_{k}-x_{k+1}}{V_{k+1}})^\gamma + \frac{\lambda}{(\gamma+1)\eta}*\frac{\nu_{k+1}^2}{\sigma_{k}}]^\frac{1}{\gamma}, MAXPOV), MINPOV)
$

$
Objective = \frac{\eta*\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sigma_k\frac{(x_{k-1}-x_k)^{\gamma+1}}{V_{k}^\gamma}}{\sqrt{mean(x)}}+\frac{\lambda*\sum_{k=1}^{N}x_{k-1}^2\nu_k^2}{orderqty^2}
$

I have this recursive formula for a finite sequence. $X_N$ and $X_{N-1}$ is known. All those V, sigma, eta, gamma are known.
So I would like to deduce the whole sequence $x_1$, $x_2$,..., $x_{N-2}$(around 200 numbers). But the square root component is really giving me a headache because it depends on the whole sequence.

Is it solvable? Please can anyone shed some light on how to calculate the whole sequence? Or how to simplify the calculation?

Comment: Please write out the formula here, instead of asking users to chase it offsite. There is help available with formatting math on this site.

Comment: updated the formula. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to deduce $x_{n-2},x_{n-3},\dots$? or are you trying to deduce $x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\dots$?

Comment: I'm trying to deduce $x_1$, $x_2$,..., $x_{N-2}$.

Comment: I think... instead of a recursing formula, it is more like a set of equations...

Comment: @JetfiRex Could you please be more specific? I don’t quite get it.